# How to show Kotlin style issues in Android Studio Electric Eel and newer

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Older versions of Android Studio had this handy style issue check under:

Preferences > Editor > Inspections > Kotlin > Style Issues > File is not formatted according to project settings

You could set it to a warning to get visible style issue highlights as you edit. This option appears to be gone in newer versions. Was it moved or replaced with an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `Editor` -> `Inspections` -> `General` -> `Incorrect formatting`.

Description:

> Reports formatting issues that appear if your code doesn't follow your project's code style settings.
>
> This inspection is not compatible with languages that require third-party formatters for code formatting, for example, Go or C with CLangFormat enabled.